# no info with dmidecode -t 17

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I'm trying to check memory fault in Ubuntu server on Virtualbox.
and I get no info with dmidecode -t 17

[screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVrue.png)

is it because the machine is VM on virtualbox? I've checked on the Ubuntu server on ESXI but I got the info. Could you kindly let me know how to get RAM(HW) info? Could you kindly let me know how to check RAM fault?

Thank you very much.

Comment: *Why* do you think that diagnosing memory problems in a VM is relevant? If you have bad memory, check the *host*.

Comment: What was the original memory fault? Edit your question to add the details from log files. Certainly hardware faults can happen, but we would like to see problem symptoms.